# Want to set scanning options programmatically (Leadtools SDK)

Tags: c#, image-processing, c#-4.0, scanning, leadtools-sdk

When I scan document via Leadtools SDK using sample code that provided by Leadtools. It show me scanning options form. I don't want to show this scanning options(form) to user.

**How can I hide this and set scanning options programmatically?** I have gone through leadtools documentations and example but couldn't find.

Sceenshot of sanning options is attached [Scanning Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGbLp.jpg)

```
    WiaAcquireFlags flags = WiaAcquireFlags.None;
    bool showProgress = true;
    _progressDlg = new ProgressForm("Transferring", "", 100);
    _wiaAcquiring = true;

    if (_showUserInterface)
    {
        flags = WiaAcquireFlags.UseCommonUI | WiaAcquireFlags.ShowUserInterface;
    }
    else
    {           
        if (SelectAcquireSource() != System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            _wiaAcquiring = false;
            return;
        }
    }

    if (_showUserInterface && _wiaVersion == WiaVersion.Version2)
        showProgress = false;

    if (showProgress)
        _progressDlg.Show();

    _wiaSession.AcquireOptions = _wiaAcquireOptions;
    _transferMode = (_wiaProperties.DataTransfer.TransferMode == WiaTransferMode.None) ? WiaTransferMode.Memory : _wiaProperties.DataTransfer.TransferMode;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, if you do not want to show the user interface of the scanner, you should not pass the WiaAcquireFlags for ShowUserInterface and instead use WiaAcquireFlags.None.
https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19/dh/wa/wiaacquireflags.html
In the code you pasted above, you need to ensure that _showUserInterface is set to false.

If you want to set the properties programmatically, you can use the WiaSession.SetPropertyXXX() methods. For example, if your device (scanner) supports setting the X and Y resolution values, you can do it using code like this:

```
_wiaSession.SetPropertyLong(_selectedWiaItem, null, WiaPropertyId.ScannerItemXRes, 300);
_wiaSession.SetPropertyLong(_selectedWiaItem, null, WiaPropertyId.ScannerItemYRes, 300);
```

https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19/dh/wa/wiasession-setpropertylong.html

Comment: selectedWiaItem is null. How can i set selectedWiaItem variable.It is not setting/assigning anywhere in sample code. Sample code that provided by leadtools

Comment: If I set this like " _selectedWiaItem = _wiaSession.GetRootItem(null);". Then it gives exception. "Invalid parameter passed"